# Custom UIButton background after orientation change

Tags: ios, swift2

Learning Swift.
I have an `UIButton` class. Here is it:

```
class CustomBtn: UIButton {
    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var shadowAdded: Bool = false

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

    }


    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        shadowLayer                 = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.path            = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor       = UIColor(netHex: Colors.Red1.value).CGColor
        shadowLayer.shadowColor     = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath      = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset    = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity   = 0.8
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius    = 2

        layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

[image]

But when I change orientation:

[image]

What would you do to get the button background (red color and the shadow) fill the width in any orientation?

Comment: Why not use size classes and auto layout? and to make it more responsive use stack views that should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to override `drawRect` for this, so is best to heed the advice in the comment above it. But, the problem is you are setting your layers path based on your button's bounds, but those bounds change when you rotate the device, but you're not updating your layer.

Also many of the effects you're trying to achieve can be done by setting properties on your button's layer itself. I would change your class to this:

```
class CustomBtn: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){

        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: Colors.Red1.value).CGColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius    = 5

        self.layer.shadowColor     = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset    = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity   = 0.8
        self.layer.shadowRadius    = 2
    }
}
```

You can get your class to be slightly more performant by adding to `commonInit`:

```
    self.layer.shadowPath      = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5).CGPath
```

But if you do that you'll also want to add:

```
   override var bounds: CGRect{
        didSet{
            self.commonInit()
        }
    }
```

So anytime the bounds change your shadow path will be updated.